# Joining tables with set data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am building the underlying database for a shop.  There are 2 tables, one for garments and one which holds standard size charts.  Garments are available in one or more sizes and the size charts contain several measurements for each size garment.

Example size chart table

```
id  size    waist   chest   hips    height
0   6       56      76      82      160
0   8       60      80      86      162
0   10      64      84      90      164
0   12      68      88      94      166 
1   6       57      75      82      160
1   8       61      79      86      162
1   10      62      83      90      164
1   12      63      87      94      166
```

Example garments table

```
garment_id  garment_name    garment_type    size_chart  available_sizes
0           Boating Jacket  jacket          0           8,10,12      
1           Polka Dot Skirt skirt           1           10,12
```

What I want to do is join them so that I have

```
    garment_id ...  size_chart  available_sizes  size_chart.id  size_chart.size       size_chart.(...)
    0          ...   0          8,10,12      0                  8
    0          ...   0          8,10,12      0                  10
    0          ...   0          8,10,12      0                  12
    1          ...   1          10,12        1                  10
    1          ...   1          10,12        1                  12
```

The problem I am having is how to join so that I get every number in the set (available_size) to have a corresponding entry for measurements....

Any ideas/suggestions/advice on how I am best to do this would be really useful!

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone who replied! I went with @Eugen Rick 's answer in the end as it seams a like the neatest way to do this and allowed me more functionality that i had not actually perceived.  Thanks one and all for posting, all massively helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example garments table

```
garment_id  garment_name    garment_type    size_chart  available_sizes
0           Boating Jacket  jacket          0           8,10,12      
1           Polka Dot Skirt skirt           1           10,12
```

Is the root of all evil - so, speak after me:

**I will never ever store more than one information in a single db field, if I want to access them seperately. Never.**

On a more serious note, you would want to drop the `available_sizes` field from the `garments` table, instead do something like

```
CREATE TABLE available_sizes (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  garment_id INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX(garment_id),
  size_id INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX(size_id)
)
```

and populate it. This makes it easy to mark one size as sold out, maybe even add a `qty_in_stock INT` to the table, search for all garments of same type, which are available in a specific size, etc.

Comment: LOL! Ok, so I should make a seperate row and have composite primary keys for each, beign id and size.  Guess I can spilt the actual garment info (colour name etc) into another table to avoid duplication.

Comment: See my edits. I am not sure about the colors (I am not a fashion guy) - if you just have "red" this might be an idea, but if you have "jupiter-red", "fire-red", "cherry-red", "foo-red" a.s.o you might just want to store them as text.

Comment: Never say never.  The general rule as I have always heard it, is, first normalize, then optimize (for speed), where necessary.

Comment: @bnieland exactly: combining more than one information in a single db field, **if you want to access them seperately** will help with neither normalization nor optimization

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is using Dynamic SQL. From memory, it would be simething like this:

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000)

declare @id int
select @id = 0

declare @inVariable varchar(20)
select @inVariable = NULL

while(true)
begin
    select @inVariable = availables_sizes from garment where id = @id

    if (@inVariable <> NULL OR @inVariable <> '')
    begin

        if(@id > 0)
        begin
            select @cmd =
            ' UNION select g.garment_id, g.size_chart, g.availables_sizes, c.id, c.size
            from garments g
            inner join chart c on g.size_chart = c.id
                  and c.id = ' + convert(varchar, @id) + ' 
                  and c.size in (' + @invariable + ')'
        end
        else
        begin
            select @cmd =
            'select g.garment_id, g.size_chart, g.availables_sizes, c.id, c.size
            from garments g
            inner join chart c on g.size_chart = c.id
                  and c.id = ' + convert(varchar, @id) + ' 
                  and c.size in (' + @invariable + ')'
        end

        select @id = @id + 1
    end
    else
    begin
        break
    end
end

exec(@cmd)
```

---

Now, like @EugenRieck stated, this is evil!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) for all the rows and then a sub-select *inside* the initial SELECT clause to list the sizes in one column.